# UnderscoreJS: Group a collection by attribute, sort by result length and get top 100 in array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

JavaScript:

```
Template.list.jobs = function() {
  if(Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')) {
    jobs = Jobs.find({onet: Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')}).fetch();
    // Session.set('jobCount', jobs.count());

    var cnt = _.groupBy(jobs, 'address')
    var tmp = []
    $.each(cnt, function(indx, val){
      tmp[indx] = _.size(val);
    });

    return Pagination.collection(jobs);
  } else {
    jobs = Jobs.find()
    Session.set('jobCount', jobs.count());
    return Pagination.collection(jobs.fetch());
  }
}
```

I am trying to take my `groupBy`, sort it and grab the top 100 results.

The array that is grouped looks like this:

```
{
  "Adelphi, MD": [{
    _id: "fv2xCQt6T37f36vGH"
    address: "Adelphi, MD"
    company: "General Technical Services, LLC"
    dateacquired: "2014-1-16 9:41 PM"
    jvid: "3cc86df5855c4a6599e595ad1a5b18e9321"
    lat: ""
    lng: ""
    onet: "17-0000.00"
    title: "Technician / Electrician"
    url: "http://my.jobs/3cc86df5855c4a6599e595ad1a5b18e9321"
  }]
}
```

Each key in the array is a city/state name, I am wanting to count each array, sort by the count and then take the top 100.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the question, this returns a sorted (max to min) array of the top 100:

```
var compareLengthOfSecondElement = function(a, b) {
        return a[1].length < b[1].length;
    }

var result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('address')
    .pairs()
    .sort(compareLengthOfSecondElement)
    .slice(0, 100)
    .value();
```